# InsertOrUpdate throwing error for identity primary column

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, linq2db

I was following article for InsertOrUpdate using Entity Framework Core and SQL Server.

http://blog.linq2db.com/2015/05/linq-crud-operations.html

So my linq2db query is same as their documentation.

```
using (var db = new DataConnection())
{
    db.GetTable<TestTable3>()
        .InsertOrUpdate(
            () => new TestTable3
            {
                ID   = 5,
                Name = "Crazy Frog",
            },
            t => new TestTable3
            {
                Name = "Crazy Frog IV",
            });
}
```

But in my case `Id` is auto incremented identity primary column. So I am getting error as below.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TestTable3' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.'
```

Now I know that identity column cannot be provided. But if I don't provide then it is throwing error as

```
LinqToDB.Linq.LinqException: 'InsertOrUpdate method requires the 'TestTable3.Id' field to be included in the insert setter.'
```

Comment: Actually identity column can  be populated by explicit value https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-identity-insert Am not sure it is best practice for MS SQL,  IDENTITY_INSERT will also reseed

Comment: but i also need auto increment in case of insert.

Comment: Increment in case of insert will work even when IDENTITY_INSERT is set, just increment of which value? I suppose after inserting of 5 will be reseed to 6. Cannot check, MS SQL connection does not work on sqlfiddle now

Comment: @vitalygolub, please notice huge difference between EF Core and linq2db. linq2db do not have Change Tracker, which gives more control of what has been sent SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need retrieving just inserted value, there is overload of InsertOrUpdate function which has additional parameter for duplicate key:

```
using (var db = new DataConnection())
{
    db.GetTable<TestTable3>().InsertOrUpdate(
        () => new TestTable3
        {
            Name = "Crazy Frog"
        },
        e => new TestTable3
        {
            Name = "Crazy Frog"
        },
        () => new TestTable3
        {
            ID = 5
        });
}
```